# Google Natural language api python goes to an infinite loop

Tags: python, google-natural-language

I'm using google natural language api to analyse the sentiment in a sentence. But, every time I run the script. It goes to an infinite loop of sleep.

My code.

```
comments = "This product is really good"
credentials = GoogleAuth.get_instance()
client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
document = types.Document(
    content=comments,
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
)
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)
```

Stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_mac/app/sentiment_analysis_runner.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/my_mac/app/sentiment_analysis_runner.py", line 8, in main
    sentiment = sentiment_analyser.analyse(url)
  File "/Users/my_mac/app/sentiment_analysis/product_sentiment_analysis.py", line 20, in analyse
    return self.analyse_comments(comments)
  File "/Users/my_mac/app/sentiment_analysis/product_sentiment_analysis.py", line 32, in analyse_comments
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)
  File "/Users/my_mac/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/language_v1/gapic/language_service_client.py", line 230, in analyze_sentiment
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/Users/my_mac/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_mac/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 270, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/my_mac/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 205, in retry_target
    time.sleep(sleep)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following code, based on the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) documentation, and it worked without issues.

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
from google.oauth2 import service_account

#Setting the Service Account key
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('../key.json')
client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
text = u'This product is really good'
document = types.Document(
    content=text,
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment

print('Text: {}'.format(text))
print('Sentiment: {}, {}'.format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

And got the output:

```
Text: This product is really good
Sentiment: 0.800000011921, 0.800000011921
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There was an issue with the credentials object I was passing into LanguageServiceClient. Not sure why it was not throwing an error. But, thanks for your response.

Comment: HI @Aakash , good to know you solved your issue. Could you please post your solution as it may help the community if they had this same issue?

Comment: It just was a silly mistake, really. I had to access the auth variable to get the credentials like this ... credentials = GoogleAuth.get_instance().auth. But, not sure why I wasn't getting an error when I passed an object to the LanguageServiceClient. I'm pretty new to python and still trying to figure out.

Comment: **@Aakash** could you specify the documentation you are using to determine it was required to add the `auth` part to the `GoogleAuth.get_instance()` method? I have been making a research and I haven't been able to find information about this method. Additionally, it would be great if you can add the libraries you are implementing.